# Looking for a regex to match all operators: + - * / = > < >= <= & | % ! ^ ( )

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to use regex to see if a given string is any one of the above operators, and nothing else. Example

```
var a = "3 + 2" //match fail
var b = ">=" //match pass
```

The regEx test must confirm if my given string is ONLY one of the above operators. It may not be an operator and a combination of something else.

Is there a standard regEx expression for just operators?

Comment: You basically wrote it on the question.

Comment: For everything related to regexes, I'll suggest https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: Yes,  a character set containing all those characters, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets.

Comment: You just have to escape all special character from your sequence: RegExp.escape = function(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};

Comment: Sorry, guys my question was too ambiguous - I've rephrased the context

Comment: Please express you question more clearly. "A given string is one of the above operators" means what? DO you mean, "A given string is composed only of the above operators"?

Comment: @MarzSocks Again, your title is almost the regex, delta the special chars you need to escape.

Comment: WIth regard to `<=`, think about it. If you check that the string contains `<` and `=`, then you don't need another check to see that it contains `<=`.

Comment: If you're trying to check for a single case of any of one- or two-character operators, use the "alternation" operation `|`.

Comment: Since I revised my question - all you guys who down voted should re-consider. The accepted answer is not "how you write the question". There are some escaping concepts that need to be explained. And there is not a similar question on stackoverflow as  far as I can tell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just

```
/^(\+|-|\*|\/|=|>|<|>=|<=|&|\||%|!|\^|\(|\))$/
```

Or, for readability and maintainability:

```
var ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '&', '|', '^', '(', ')'];
var regexp = new RegExp(
    '^(' +
    ops.map(function(op) { return '\\' + op; }).join('|') +
    + ')$');
```

Comment: Its the escaping that kept throwing me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
^(\+|-|\*|/|=|>|<|>=|<=|&|\||%|!|\^|\(|\))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Sktp35DAYkmpstth)